# Simple AD - change domain membership

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, activedirectorymembership, amazon-directory-services

I have one Simple AD configured in a **primary** AWS account and a few Windows EC2 instances are joined to this Simple AD. I want to migrate my **primary** account Windows instances which are joined to the Simple AD of the **primary** AWS account to my **secondary** AWS account and need to join those instances with the Simple AD instance in the **secondary** account.

To do that I have created AMIs of the servers in the **primary** AWS account and shared the *AMIs* of the servers to my **secondary** AWS account.

After creating an instance from the shared AMI in the **secondary account** I am not able to login into the instance and not able to unjoin the instance from my **primary** Simple AD domain controller.

Please suggest me how to unjoin the instance from the primary domain controller in my **secondary** AWS account.

N.B I am not able to unjoin the instance in my primary AWS account those are production servers.
Please suggest me is there any way I can unjoin the instance in secondary AWS account and joined the instance with the new domain controller.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to join the instances in the secondary account to the Simple AD in the secondary account? As the Simple AD in the primary account is not contactable from the secondary account you'll need to login as a local administrator user to join the domain in the secondary account.

Comment: While I have joined the windows instance in simple AD domain then I am not able to login the instance with local admin account. That is why I am not able to change the domain name in the instance.

Comment: If you're unable to login as a local admin, try [resetting the Administrator password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Launch.html).